# Why explicit hint provides better performance?

Tags: mongodb

I feel a bit confusing with how index works. If fill up database with documents with keys **a**, **b**, and **c**, each of which has random value (except **c**, it has incrementing value)

Here is python code I used:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from random import Random
r = Random()

client = MongoClient("server")
test_db = client.test
fubar_col = test_db.fubar

for i in range(100000):
    doc = {'a': r.randint(10000, 99999), 'b': r.randint(100000, 999999), 'c': i}
    fubar_col.insert(doc)
```

Then I create an index *{c: 1}*

Now, if I perform

```
>db.fubar.find({'a': {$lt: 50000}, 'b': {$gt: 500000}}, {a: 1, c: 1}).sort({c: -1}).explain()
```

I got

```
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor c_1 reverse",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 24668,
    "nscannedObjects" : 100000,
    "nscanned" : 100000,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 100869,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 100869,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 1,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 478,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "c" : [
            [
                {
                    "$maxElement" : 1
                },
                {
                    "$minElement" : 1
                }
            ]
        ]
    },
    "server" : "nuclight.org:27017"
}
```

See, mongodb uses **c_1** index and it takes about 478 millisecond to perform. And if I specify which index I want to use ( via hint({c: 1}) ):

```
> db.fubar.find({'a': {$lt: 50000}, 'b': {$gt: 500000}}, {a: 1, c: 1}).sort({c: -1}).hint({c:1}).explain()
```

It takes only about 167 milliseconds. Why it happens?

Here is link to json dump of fubar collection [fubar.tgz](https://mega.co.nz/#!Y44BDDjK!d6ud-VzmH0uIsL0RXqINU3v3IzB5aeop_8I5bE922e4)

p.s. I performed these queries several times and result are the same

Comment: What other indexes exist on this collection? It clearly is using that index because it is being forced to or has no choice, not because it is optimal

Comment: I believe this is to do with the way MongoDB tests and uses the race condition of indexes to understand which to use, however, I am confused as to why MongoDB is seemly not caching the index result if you tried the query 7 times with the same results.

Comment: What do you get if your hint is on {c: -1} rather than {c: 1}? You original query is reverse iterating where your hint is not. Not sure if it should make a difference but could be impacting results.

Answer (score 2):

`explain` forces MongoDB to re-evaluate all query plans. In a 'normal' query, the cached fastest query plan will be used. From [the documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/explain/) (emphasis mine):

> The `explain()` operation evaluates the set of query plans and reports
>   on the winning plan for the query. In *normal operations the query
>   optimizer caches winning query plans* and uses them for similar related
>   queries in the future. As a result MongoDB may sometimes select query
>   plans from the cache that are different from the plan displayed using
>   `explain()`.

Unless you really need to iterate the entire result set for a typical query, you might want to include `limit()` in your query. In your particular example, using `limit(100)` will return a `BasicCursor` When using `explain`, not the index:

```
> db.fubar.find({'a': {$lt: 50000}, 'b': {$gt: 500000}}).sort({c: -1}).hint({c:1}).limit(100).explain();
{
        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor c_1 reverse",
        "n" : 100,
        "nscanned" : 432,
        "nscannedAllPlans" : 432,
        "scanAndOrder" : false,
        "millis" : 3,
        "indexBounds" : {
                "c" : [[{"$maxElement" : 1}, {"$minElement" : 1}]]
        },
}
>
> db.fubar.find({'a': {$lt: 50000}, 'b': {$gt: 500000}}).sort({c: -1}).limit(100).explain();
{
        "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
        "n" : 100,
        "nscanned" : 431,
        "nscannedAllPlans" : 863,
        "scanAndOrder" : true,
        "millis" : 12,
        "indexBounds" : { },
}
```

Note that this is a somewhat pathological case, because using the index doesn't help too much (compare `nscanned`).

Comment: f.find({a: {$gt: 90000}, b: {$lt: 110000}}).sort({c: 1}).limit(100).explain() and takes 800 mills to perform with c_1 index and 68 mills without it

f.find({a: {$gt: 50000}, b: {$lt: 500000}}).sort({c: 1}).limit(100).explain() without index takes 260 mills, and with c_1 - only 8.

Comment: It depends on the order of the data: in some cases, iterating along the 'c' index might quickly find items that match the `a` and `b` criteria. In other cases, it's a lot faster using natural order. The problem: your `c` index doesn't help in filtering elements, but only in ordering them (which isn't necessary if you used the `c` index in the first place). Combined range queries are a bit painful. Don't use an explicit hint and remember that `explain` is often a lot slower than regular queries. For perf. optimization, use the integrated profiler.